# Writing data on Firestore sudden fail with Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have 5 scheduled function in Cloud Function, everything works fine for months but then this day it suddenly seems to fail or did not wait for the Firestore to finish updating. Is this some timeout or service downtime? Currently all 5 scheduled functions calls `updateFunction()` to update some field in the Firestore document but only this time that the update part did not succeed.

```
'use-strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
/*
 * 'onCreate' triggered when a document is written to for the first time.
 * 'onDelete' triggered when a document with data is deleted.
 * 'OnWrite' works as 'addValueEventListener' or 'addSnapshotListener' for android.
 * It will fire the function every time there is some item added, removed or changed 
 * from the provided 'database.ref'.
 *
*/
const settingsConfig = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };

const db = admin.firestore();
db.settings(settingsConfig);


//Message priority must be one of normal or high.
const options = { priority: 'high' };

exports.schedTask3 = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 11 * * 1')
    .timeZone('Asia/Manila') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
    .onRun((context) => {
        //This will be run every Monday at 11:00 AM

        updateFunction();

    });

//THIS FUNCTION IS BEING USE BY 5 SCHEDULE FUNCTION (schedTask1 to schedTask5)
function updateFunction() {

    const dateFormat = require('dateformat');

    dateFormat.i18n = {
        dayNames: [
            'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat',
            'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'
        ],
        monthNames: [
            'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec',
            'Januari', 'Februari', 'Maret', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Agustus', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Desember'
        ],
        timeNames: [
            'a', 'p', 'am', 'pm', 'A', 'P', 'AM', 'PM'
        ]
    };

//SUDDENLY DID NOT REACH THEN RESULT FOR THE FIRST TIME AFTER MONTHS OF WORKING
    return db
        .collection("Lorem")
        .doc("Lorem")
        .set({
            date: dateFormat(new Date().getTime(), "dd mmmm yyyy"),
            value: "Lorem"
        })
        .then(result => {

            const payload = {
                data: {
                    title: "Lorem",
                    description: "Lorem",
                    bigImage: "Lorem",
                    link: "Lorem",
                    environment: "release",
                }
            };

            pushNotif(payload);

            console.log("Updating prediction is success.");

        }).catch(error => {
            return console.error("Failed to send notification.", error);
        })

}


function pushNotif(payload) {

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("Announcement", payload, options)
        .then(val => {
            return console.log("Success!\n" + JSON.stringify(payload), val);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return console.error("Failed to send notification.", error);
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you incorrectly manage the life cycle of your Cloud Function.

It is important to return a Promise (or a value) in background Cloud Functions calling asynchronous methods in order to tell the Cloud Functions platform to wait until the promise is fulfilled or rejected before cleaning up the function. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions for more detail.

In your case, the following happens: Sometimes, the Cloud Functions platform does not clean up your Cloud Function immediately and the Cloud Function can complete. But in other cases, **since you don't return a promise**, the  Cloud Functions platform cleans it up **before completion**.

The following changes (see, among others, the addition of several `return`s) should do the trick (untested):

```
'use-strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
/*
 * 'onCreate' triggered when a document is written to for the first time.
 * 'onDelete' triggered when a document with data is deleted.
 * 'OnWrite' works as 'addValueEventListener' or 'addSnapshotListener' for android.
 * It will fire the function every time there is some item added, removed or changed 
 * from the provided 'database.ref'.
 *
*/
const settingsConfig = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };

const db = admin.firestore();
db.settings(settingsConfig);


//Message priority must be one of normal or high.
const options = { priority: 'high' };

exports.schedTask3 = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 11 * * 1')
    .timeZone('Asia/Manila') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
    .onRun((context) => {
        //This will be run every Monday at 11:00 AM

        return updateFunction()
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                return null;
            })

    });

//THIS FUNCTION IS BEING USE BY 4 SCHEDULE FUNCTION (schedTask1 to schedTask5)
function updateFunction() {

    const dateFormat = require('dateformat');

    dateFormat.i18n = {
        dayNames: [
            'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat',
            'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'
        ],
        monthNames: [
            'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec',
            'Januari', 'Februari', 'Maret', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Agustus', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Desember'
        ],
        timeNames: [
            'a', 'p', 'am', 'pm', 'A', 'P', 'AM', 'PM'
        ]
    };

    //SUDDENLY DID NOT REACH THEN RESULT FOR THE FIRST TIME AFTER MONTHS OF WORKING
    return db
        .collection("Lorem")
        .doc("Lorem")
        .set({
            date: dateFormat(new Date().getTime(), "dd mmmm yyyy"),
            value: "Lorem"
        })
        .then(result => {

            const payload = {
                data: {
                    title: "Lorem",
                    description: "Lorem",
                    bigImage: "Lorem",
                    link: "Lorem",
                    environment: "release",
                }
            };

            return pushNotif(payload);


        }).catch(error => {
            // throw an error e.g. throw new Error('....'), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error
        })

}


function pushNotif(payload) {

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("Announcement", payload, options)
        .then(val => {
            console.log("Success!\n" + JSON.stringify(payload), val);
            return null;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // throw an error e.g. throw new Error('....'), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error
        });

}
```

---

I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/.

Comment: That's it! Thank you for helping me on understanding what is the wrong with these code out of a sudden.